# Why are setInterval calls not throttled for the first 4 executions?

Tags: javascript, browser, setinterval, throttling

It is a known fact that timeouts in JavaScript are throttled [every 4ms on an active tab and every 1000ms on an inactive one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). This behavior may slightly change, depending on the browser and configuration, but it is usually the same.

For completeness, I'll quote here the relevant part:

> Timeouts throttled to >=4ms
>
> In modern browsers, `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` calls are throttled to a minimum of once every 4ms when successive calls are triggered due to callback nesting (where the nesting level is at least a certain depth), or after certain number of successive intervals.

I wanted to prove that to someone by using this snippet on a default Chrome instance:

```js
let beforeStartingTheInterval = Date.now();
let intervalId = setInterval(()=>{ 
  let msPassed = Date.now()-beforeStartingTheInterval;
  if (msPassed > 20) clearInterval(intervalId); // stop after 20 ms
  console.log( msPassed + "ms have passed after starting the interval")
  }
,0);
```

And almost every time I ran that code, I got this output:

```
1ms have passed after starting the interval
2ms have passed after starting the interval
3ms have passed after starting the interval
4ms have passed after starting the interval
8ms have passed after starting the interval
12ms have passed after starting the interval
16ms have passed after starting the interval
20ms have passed after starting the interval
```

As can be seen, the interval is *(usually)* ran once per millisecond the first four times, and every >=4ms afterwards.

Why is it that for the first 4 executions, the calls are not throttled? I expected this output:

```
4ms have passed after starting the interval
8ms have passed after starting the interval
12ms have passed after starting the interval
16ms have passed after starting the interval
20ms have passed after starting the interval
```

Or at least one that has a minimum of 4ms between any two executions (even the first ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that for the first 4 executions, the calls are not throttled?

I guess the first question that should be asked is *Why is the timer throttled at all?*

Well some easons could be, that such short running timers are

1) difficult to implement as you either have to use a hardware timer or check the time inside a loop, to be able to shedule times accurately the loop has to run very fast.

2) consuming a lot of battery / computing time

3) are probably not needed at all as the display gets updated roughly every 60fps, which is every 16ms, so if you use a timer that runs that fast, you won't actually see the output in that speed.

The next question could then be *Why does one use such short timers at all then?*

There are actually a few good reasons:

1) To defer an action after
 a) the current code block, take React's setState for example
 b) a DOM rerender

2) To execute a long running tasks "asynchronously" on the main thread without blocking the UI, through freeing it for a millisecond some time.

Therefore the browser has a problem when adjusting the timer time:

If it clamps the time of e.g. `setState` by 4ms, the page might load slower overall. If it however does not throttle a setInterval that runs unnecessarily fast, it wastes the users battery (most users are on a mobile these days).

Therefore it makes sense that the browser executes a few timers very fast, so that `setTimeout(deferred, 0)` gets executed immeadiately, but then throttles after a few times, to reduce the negative impact of wrongly made render timers / long running algorithms.

The "4ms" after "5 times" are probably the balanced outcome of that consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [documentation that you linked to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) (emphasis mine)

> In Chrome and Firefox, the ***5th successive callback call is clamped***; Safari clamps on the 6th call; in Edge its the 3rd one. Gecko started to treat setInterval() like this in version 56 (it already did this with setTimeout(); see below).

Comment: I did not see that as the "why" I'm asking for

Comment: @Adelin Why? Because that's how it's specified by browser makers. What more is there to say about it?

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the web some more, I found that this is an [HTML5 standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers):

> Note: Timers can be nested; after **five** such nested timers, however, the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/

> Most browsers also do some sort of timer throttling based on different conditions. The intent is to save battery at opportune times – times when, theoretically, you either won’t notice the difference or would gladly trade for improved battery life on a laptop or mobile device. Here are some circumstances where timer resolution changes: